# The newly created variables are showing as null values while executing in stored procedures in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

```
create procedure dbo.test_sp --Creating the procedure 
    @country varchar(50) = NULL,  
    @from_date date = NULL,
    @to_date date = NULL,
    @month varchar(50) = NULL,
    @year varchar(50) = NULL
as
    declare @start_date date 
    declare @end_date date
    declare @day_value date

    select 
        sum(value) end as sumofamount,
        (select min(date) 
         from test_data 
         where month = @month and year = @year) as start_date, -- Creating new variable
        (select max(date) 
         from test_data 
         where month = @month and year = @year) as end_date, -- Creating new variable
        (select try_convert(date,concat(@day , '/' , @month, '/',@year) as day_value -- Creating new variable
         from test_data
         where country = isnull(@country, country)  
           and date_test between isnull(@from_date,date_test) and isnull(@to_date, date_test)
go

--Declaring the variables and calling them as parameters in stored procedures
declare @start_date date
declare @day_value date

exec dbo.test_sp 
         @country = 'India',
         @from_date = @start_date, 
         @to_date = @day_value,
         @month = 'May',
         @year = '2018'
```

The newly created variables enters as null values in the where clause

Comment: Pls be more careful when you tag a question. MySQL is not the same as ms sql server!

Comment: Any of created and not initialized variables are NULL

Comment: if you're referring to `@start_date` and `@day_value` then these aren't initialised to anything

Comment: "*The newly created variables enters as null values*" for sure, they are newly created, without any value set

Comment: Your comments in your query are quite confusing. Selecting data from a table does not create a new variable. And holy cow is that query way over complicated. The formatting is so painful it is hard to decipher exactly what is going on there but you don't need subqueries for each column.

Comment: how to save the output of a sub query into a variable like start_date and use as a parameter in the stored procedure ?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[test_sp]
(
   @country varchar(50) = NULL 
  ,@from_date date = NULL
  ,@to_date date = NULL
  ,@month varchar(50) = NULL
  ,@year varchar(50) = NULL
  ,@day varchar(2) = NULL
) AS
  BEGIN
    Declare @Start_date AS DATE
    Declare @End_date AS DATE
    Declare @Day_value AS DATE

SET @Start_date = (SELECT min(date) FROM [test_data] WHERE month = @month)
SET @End_date = (SELECT max(date) FROM [test_data] WHERE month = @month)
SET @Day_value = (SELECT try_convert(date,concat(@day , '/' , @month, '/',@year) FROM [test_data])

select @start_Date
select @end_Date
select @day_value

select sum(value) from test_data where country = ISNULL(@country,country) 
AND date_test BETWEEN  ISNULL(@from_date,date_test) AND ISNULL(@to_date,date_test)
END

declare @start_date date
declare @end_date date
exec test_sp  @country = 'India'
,@from_date  = @start_date
,@to_date  = @end_date
,@month  = NULL
,@year  = NULL
,@day  = NULL
```